# How can I know which version SharePoint I am using and onPrem or Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am using SharePoint I want to know the version like 2015, 2019 and is it SP Online or SP onPrem.

How can I know this information without assuming like, guessing from UI and menus. Just I want to see it clearly?

When I click on **?** icon

[image]

Comment: SharePoint does not have a version button or about box with version info. If there are no customizations applied in your site then you can clearly identify the version from UI only. see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/which-version-of-sharepoint-am-i-using-3575ff57-037f-48cf-9398-99080c34b25f).

Comment: Also, you can know this using PowerShell like mentioned [here](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=357) and [here](https://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-check-sharepoint-online-version/). See similar question on this forum, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511590/how-to-get-version-of-sharepoint-installed).

Comment: Do you have an access to SharePoint Administration Center ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **don't have** an access to SharePoint Administration Center or any SP server, click on **?** on SharePoint homepage.

[image]

You will see a version number in Help window

[image]

If you **have** an access to SharePoint Admin Center, Login to Admin Center, navigate to *Servers in Farm* section, you will see build version of installed SharePoint. And then you can google build version or check it on this [site](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346).

Also you can execute PowerShell command -

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.BuildVersion
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I am getting three options when I click on ? icon. See my updated question.

Comment: @R15 click on Help

Comment: @R15 do you have any result?

Comment: On clicking help I navigated to another page. There I found based on instruction I am using SP online and version is 2019. :). Before I ignored when saw long article but now I have read that.

Answer (score 0):

Here're some references about methods to check SharePoint version for you:

[Which version of SharePoint am I using?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/which-version-of-sharepoint-am-i-using-3575ff57-037f-48cf-9398-99080c34b25f)

[How to Check Your SharePoint Version?](https://www.brightwork.com/blog/how-to-check-your-sharepoint-version)